# Is there a viewport screen mode config that fits every size phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen, viewport

I've used a combination of viewport screen modes, but they tend not to work when tested across phones and platforms.

An example of the code I've been using to have a 480px wide html document as defined using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) href="mobile.css" />
```

has been:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different screen sizes that it's a losing battle to try to set styles for all of them. A better approach (arguably) is to focus on the natural breakpoints for your own content, and set up @media rules (if necessary) to reflow content where needed. You can easily test for these breakpoints by narrowing and widening your browser window. Then you'll know that, whatever the screen size, you've covered all bases, and the content will flow appropriately for that device.